# Magento 2 : One Step Checkout Update tax amount based on change country/state/zip

Tags: magento2, onestepcheckout

Currently, the Tax amount update when we user selects a shipping method I want to update the tax amount on the checkout **page when the user selects or changes country/state/zip code.**

Does anyone have an idea how it can be possible in Magento 2?

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious what's the use case of this settings?

I mean, you only jump to shipping method **after** entering country/zip information. If you reload on changing country then you will reload it twice, one for country change and one for shipping method change, kind of a waste of request here.

Could you give more information about the use cases? Thanks!